# Converting a Fermion to a Boson by attaching proper flux

Tags: fermions, bosons

In [this](https://www.pnas.org/content/96/16/8821) article the author says that a Fermion can be formally converted to a Boson if
the path of the Fermion encloses a single flux quantum $\phi_0 = \frac{h}{e}$. As the phase cancels
any additional statistical phase. But, this is not what I get when I calculate
\begin{align}
 \Delta \theta &= \frac{e}{\hbar} \oint_{path} \mathbf A(\mathbf r) .d\mathbf l \\
\end{align}
One can convert the path integral to surface integral which gives $\iint \mathbf B .d\mathbf{s}$
After simplifications the phase turns out to be
\begin{align}
 \Delta \theta = 2 \pi N_o
\end{align}
Here $N_o$ is the number of flux quanta enclosed by the path of the fermion. So when the path
encloses only a single flux quanta, i.e, $N_o=1$, the phase is simply $2\pi$, so
$e^{2\pi i} \phi = \phi$. Where it should be $e^{i \pi } \phi = -\phi$ so that
the statistical phase $-1$ is cancelled. Not sure, what am doing wrong.

Comment: You want one particle to go half way round the other (exchange) to get $-1$.

Comment: That means I should not do a closed line integral. This will have the same effect if I divide the closed line integral by 2 . Am I right? @mikestone

Comment: Yes. Not closed. The original paper by Zhang-Hansen-Kivelson is a good and clear read.